# How can I modify the from email address used in petition confirmation email?

Tags: email, petition

My default from email address is office@my-organisation.org. When a supporter signs a petition, they get a confirmation with that sender address. However, I want the confirmation email to have petitions@my-organisation.org as sender address. How can I achieve this?